# Android edit system.img file

Tags: android, system, image-file

I want to add certificate to my image file so latter I can start an emulator with that certificate.

```
emulator -avd my_adb_device -system path_to_image_file
```

But I don't know how to edit image files.

I been trying several things without luck.

- https://www.olimex.com/wiki/How_to_edit_prebuilt_Android_images
- http://androidforum.tytung.com/how-to-create-system-img-file-from-a-flashable-zip-t38.html

Any ideas how this can be achieved?